# Angular 12 Async Pipe Property does not exist on type string

Tags: angular, typescript, types, observable, angular12

I have a typed observable using the model

```
import { FishTypes, SelectedFish } from ...

export class Fish{
  fishTypes: FishTypes;
  selectedFish: SelectedFish;
  constructor() {
    this.fishTypes = new FishTypes;
    this.selectedFish = new SelectedFish;
  }
}
```

In my template I am able to use this typed Observable to display all the current data using

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(fishData$ | async) as fish">
  {{fish | json}}
</ng-container>
```

Which then displays:
{"fishTypes}: {...}, "selectedFish": {...}

My issue is when I try to display either

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(fishData$ | async) as fish">
  {{fish.selectedFish}} or {{fish['selectedFish']}}
</ng-container>
```

I get the error "Property 'selectedFish' does not exist on type 'string'". I know I'm just missing something small but I haven't been able to figure it out

Comment: Looks like in the description you provided wrong model class. It has non-valid things like `new FishTypes`. pls, fix it

Comment: Those themselves are other models. new FishTypes is a new instance of the FishTypes model. I've updated the question to show imports

Comment: Do you receive `fishData` from the backend? If yes, pls provide the code responsible for receiving this data

Comment: import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    let url = dburl....
    this.fishData =   this.http.get(url);
}

Comment: This returns an observable that is subscribable. I am able to get the data out in this way or using pipe, I am just unable to access it directly from the template using the async pipe

Inside the observable is this json data {selectedFish: {name: "Trout", color: "Red"}, fishTypes: {names: ["Trout", "Bass", "Flounder"...]}}

Again, if I unpack the observable I am able to access all this data. I'm just unable to use | async